# updated question on generate dynamic record based on the saved data

Tags: oracle

updated-actual-record:

[image]

updated-expected-record:

[image]

in table we have record like id 1, having std value(in roman format) (i),(ii),(iii) then record generated should be for id 1 with std value(in roman format till 6 or 8) (i),(ii),(iii),(iv),(v),(vi). but if id 1 is also having code column value then std column will be null.

```
create table t11 
    ( 
    name varchar2(20), 
    id number, 
    std varchar2(20), 
    grade varchar2(20), 
    code varchar2(20) 
    );

insert into t11 values('ram-1', 142174, '('||trim(lower(to_char(1,'RN')))||')','V',null);

insert into t11 values('ram-1', 142174, '('||trim(lower(to_char(2,'RN')))||')','N',null);

insert into t11 values('ram-1', 142174, '('||trim(lower(to_char(3,'RN')))||')','X',null);

insert into t11 values('ram-1', 142174, '('||trim(lower(to_char(4,'RN')))||')','X',null);

insert into t11 values('ram-1', 142174, null,'A','A');

insert into t11 values('ram-2', 140965, '('||trim(lower(to_char(1,'RN')))||')','N',null);

insert into t11 values('ram-2', 140965, '('||trim(lower(to_char(3,'RN')))||')','X',null);

insert into t11 values('ram-3', 140966,null,'B','B');

select * from t11;
```

one of my good friend(GMB) tried, now we need help:

```
with cte (id, name, std, grade , code) as (
    select distinct id, name, 1, grade , code from t11
    union all
    select id, name, std + 1, grade , code from cte where std < 6
)
select id, name, '('||trim(lower(to_char(std,'RN')))||')' std, grade , code 
from cte
order by id, std
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a partitioned outer join for data densification (creating rows). A partitioned outer join is a join that repeats for every instance of a value - in this case you want to apply an outer join of 7 roman numeral rows to each NAME.

This query also needs analytic functions to fill in the missing IDs. Also - is your sample data slightly wrong? Should the ram-3 value be 140966 instead of 140965?

```
select
    t11.name,
    coalesce(
        t11.id,
        lag(t11.id ignore nulls) over (partition by name order by roman_numerals.std nulls first),
        lead(t11.id ignore nulls) over (partition by name order by roman_numerals.std nulls first)
    ) test,
    roman_numerals.std,
    t11.grade,
    t11.code
from
(
    select ''      std from dual union all
    select '(i)'   std from dual union all
    select '(ii)'  std from dual union all
    select '(iii)' std from dual union all
    select '(iv)'  std from dual union all
    select '(v)'   std from dual union all
    select '(vi)'  std from dual
) roman_numerals
left outer join t11 partition by (t11.name)
    on nvl(t11.std, 'no value') = nvl(roman_numerals.std, 'no value')
order by name, roman_numerals.std nulls last;
```

Comment: yes Jon ,you are right, just updated the requirement.